# My project is working on google colab but not working on pycharm

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pycharm, google-colaboratory

My project is a handwriting digit analyzer. It is working on Google Colab but is showing an error on Pycharm. The statement that is making it work in colab is "%matplotlib inline" this line is showing an error in pycharm.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import metrics
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

mnist = fetch_openml("mnist_784")

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 4))
    for index, (image, label) in enumerate(zip(mnist.data[:5], mnist.target[:5])):
    plt.subplot(1, 5, index + 1)
    plt.imshow(np.reshape(image, (28, 28)), cmap="gray")
    plt.title("Number: %s" % label)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(mnist.data, mnist.target, test_size=0.2)
mdl = LogisticRegression(solver="lbfgs")
mdl.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = mdl.predict(X_test)
score = mdl.score(X_test, y_test)

index = 0
plt.imshow(np.reshape(X_test[index], (28, 28)))
print("Prediction: " + mdl.predict([X_test[index]])[0])

cm = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions)
plt.figure(figsize=(9, 9))
plt.imshow(cm, cmap='Pastell')
plt.title('Confusion Matrix for MNIST Data')

plt.xticks(np.arange(10))
plt.yticks(np.arange(10))

plt.ylabel('Actual Label')
plt.xlabel('Predicted Label')

plt.colorbar()

width, height = cm.shape
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        plt.annotate(str(cm[x][y]), xy=(y, x), horizontalalignment='center', 
verticalalignment='center')
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Asus\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Handwriting_Digit_Recognition\digit.py", line 15, in 
plt.imshow(np.reshape(image, (18, 18)), cmap="gray")
File "<**array_function** internals>", line 5, in reshape
File "C:\Users\Asus\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 299, in reshape
return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)
File "C:\Users\Asus\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 55, in _wrapfunc
return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
File "C:\Users\Asus\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 44, in _wrapit
result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (18,18)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%matplotlib inline` is a message to Jupyter notebook to render images into the notebook itself. You need to remove that line if you use your code from Pycharm.

Comment: i have edited the question and added the error section.

Answer (score 0):

After the for loop on line 13, try indenting all code until the
`X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(mnist.data, mnist.target, test_size=0.2)` line (but don't indent that line). The error has nothing to do with `%matplotlib inline`, but I think this is the solution. Let me know ASAP if it works. This is assuming the rest of your code works, though!
Don't forget that Python depends on indentation unlike other languages
!

Answer (score 0):

It is the problem coming from the conflict when Pycharm uses GPU. The solution is to add the code when you use tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allocator_type = 'BFC' #A "Best-fit with coalescing" algorithm, simplified from a version of dlmalloc.
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.3
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config))
```